# Как правильно составить базу данных sqlite для словаря?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Например, нужна БД для 3 языков вида `слово-значение`, правильно ли будет создать 3 таблицы по 3 столбца в каждой?

Comment: Почему не 1 таблица с 3 столбцами, хотя бы ?

Comment: В любом случае когда вы хотите создать более 1 таблицы с одинаковой структурой, есть повод задуматься, что тут что то не так, одна таблица и тип записи в ней (в вашем случае код или ID языка) более правильное решение с точки зрения реляционных баз

Comment: так я и спрашиваю правильно ли так, мои знания sql слабы поэтому хочу узнать в каком направлении двигаться

Comment: вот я и написал как примерно это выглядит. скорее всего одна таблица. (%95 что так), возможно еще вторая - справочник языков. большего по тому, что вы описали в вопросе сказать особо нечего. нет конкретики. А при разработке структуры БД важна каждая мелочь в природе данных и том, что с ними дальше предполагается делать

Comment: получается нужна одна таблица с 3 столбцами и при переключение с языка на другой язык по id языка, будет выдаваться именно нужные значения из других языков?

Comment: Я не понял, что находится в этих 3х столбцах. 1 столбец слово, 2й его описание, если я правильно понял, но в третьем что ? Хотя если ID слова то может и ok, особенно если на него потом надо будет ссылаться из других таблиц

Comment: а если такая ситуация когда по поиску "hand" выходит более развернутое описание типа "рука, часть тела" в таком случае как переключаться на другой язык там ведь ни одно слово, а целое описание

Comment: | russian | english | spanish | 
| привет | hi          | hola      | 
3 столбца примерно так

Comment: А что вы будете делать, когда у слова в данном языке несколько значений (как очень часто бывает) и надо дать переводы всех вариантов ? Тогда назревает 1я таблица: ID-слова, Язык, Слово, Описание. И вторая ID-слова1, ID-слова2. Т.е. таблица в которой ID слова "привет" и ID "hi", а так же (второй записью) ID "привет" и ID "hola"

Comment: правильно ли я понял что нужны 3 таблицы? и если это так то что взять за основу id слова

Comment: Основных я 2 вижу, третья, предположим справочник языков: ID-языка, название. Вопрос в том, а сильно ли оно надо. Вместо ID спокойно можно использоваться трехбувенные коды (RUS, ENG, ...) и программе с ними просто будет и места занимают не больше чем ID. А что касается ID то в sqlite он есть практически автоматом в каждой таблице, rowid зовется, или его можно назвать как удобно, если просто объявить поле как `integer primary key` https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: спасибо за помощь, похоже мне нужно немного почитать про связанные таблицы

Comment: как мне сделать ваш ответ решением?

Comment: Сейчас напишу как ответ, если вы об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю тут нужны минимум 2 таблицы:

Слова с описаниями:

```
create table words(
  ID integer primary key,
  lang char(3) NOT NULL,      -- Код языка (или вместо него можно сделать ID языка)
  word varchar(100) not null, -- Слово
  desc text                   -- Описание
);
```

Связи слов между собой:

```
create table word_link(
   word1 integer not null,
   word2 integer not null,
   primary key(word1, word2),
   FOREIGN KEY(word1) REFERENCES word(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY(word2) REFERENCES word(ID)
);
```

Так же можно добавить справочник языков:

```
create table languages(
  lang char(3) primary key,   -- Или числовой ID
  name varchar(100) not null  -- Наименование (для вывода в приложении)
);
```

Если такая таблица есть, то в words можно сделать FOREIGN KEY для поля LANG, что бы в него нельзя было добавить слова с несуществующими языками.

По поводу работы с таблицей word_link: Есть два варианта ее ведения, точнее поиска в ней. Есть скажем слово A в языке 1 и слова B и C в языке 2. Вопрос в том, что если мы говорим, что слова B и C являются переводами слова A, верно ли обратное утверждение, что слово A является переводом обоих слов B и C. Если да, и все переводы работают в обоих направлениях, то нам достаточно хранить только записи A-B и A-C (или наоборот C-A, B-A) и делать запрос вида:

```
select W2.*
  from words W1, word_link L, words W2
 where W1.word='A'
   and (   (L.word1=W1.ID and L.word2=W2.ID)
        or (L.word2=W1.ID and L.word1=W2.ID)
       )
   and W2.lang='ENG' -- Для поиска переводов на английский
```

Т.е. искать как прямой вариант, так и обратный, потому что мы не знаем в каком виде сохранена связь.

Но возможен и другой вариант (лучше узнавать такие тонкости у лингвистов), что хоть слова B и C считаются переводом слова A, но обратное не верно и переводом слова B является A, а переводом слова C слово A не является (или не принято так переводить). В этом случае мы учитываем направление связей и храним записи A-B, B-A, A-C (но не C-A). Поиск упрощается, исчезает второе условие в OR. Но при этом мы обязаны создавать как прямые так и обратные связи, когда они нужны.

А еще можно хранить синонимы слов из одного языка в той же таблице word_link. Делаем обычную связь и при поиске если язык word1 совпадает с языком word2 мы понимаем, что это синоним, а не перевод.

Comment: спасибо большое